# R sub with perl - starts search backwards?

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have strings that look like `a` shown below. I need to extract part of the string that is between *first* `//` and first subsequent `/`. I use `sub` with `perl = F` but it's roughly 4 times slower than with `perl = T`. So I tried `perl = T` and found that search starts from the END of the string??

```
    a = "https://moo.com/meh/woof//A.ds.serving/hgtht//ghhg/tjtke"
    print(gsub(".*//(.*?)/.*","\\1",a))

    "moo.com"

    print(gsub(".*//(.*?)/.*","\\1",a,perl=T))

    "ghhg"
```

`moo.com` is what I need. I am very surprised to see this - is it documented somewhere? How can I rewrite it with `perl` - I have 20M rows to work with, and speed is important. Thanks!

Edit: it is not given that every string will start with `http`

Comment: did you know about the package `urltools`? Comes in handy in such tasks

Comment: With TRE regex, it is not a good idea to mix lazy quantifiers with greedy ones. In some cases, they work as expected, in others, they do not. Use `perl=TRUE` in such situations, and bear in mind that `.*` matches as many chars as it can and `.*?` matches as few chars as possible, but with `perl=TRUE`, a dot does not match linebreak symbols. If you need that, add `(?s)` at the pattern start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `.*?//(.*?)/.*` to make the first `.*` lazy too so that `//` will match the first `//` instance:

```
gsub(".*?//(.*?)/.*","\\1",a,perl=T)
# [1] "moo.com"
```

And `?gsub` says:

> The standard regular-expression code has been reported to be very slow
>   when applied to extremely long character strings (tens of thousands of
>   characters or more): the code used when perl = TRUE seems much faster
>   and more reliable for such usages.
>
> The standard version of gsub does not substitute correctly repeated
>   word-boundaries (e.g. pattern = "\b"). Use perl = TRUE for such
>   matches.

Comment: Thanks! But why would `perl = F` and `T` have such different behavior?

Comment: That's a good question. Actually I am not sure, can't find any docs at the moment. I think there is something to do with how the `gsub` function works.